# finding common elements in 2 list of dicts in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 list of dicts in python as follows:

```
profile_list = [
{'name':'suzy',
'gender':'female'
},
{'name':'jim',
'gender':'male'
},
]

marks_list = [
{'name':'suzy',
'physics':95,
'chemistry':89
},
{'name':'jim',
'physics':78,
'chemistry':69
},
]
```

What would be the fastest and most efficient way to combine both these dicts so that the resultant output is as follows:

```
final_list = [
{'name':'suzy',
'gender':'female',
'marks': {'physics':95, 'chemistry': 89}
},
{'name':'jim',
'gender':'male'
'marks': {'physics':78, 'chemistry': 69}
},
]
```

Comment: `['physics':95, 'chemistry': 89]` isn't valid. Do you mean `{'physics':95, 'chemistry': 89}`?

Comment: ok..this is my first time here..only if someone could tell me what am i doing wrong before inundating me with downvotes ?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3..yes..typo..edited now..

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: thanks..i will edit the post with my efforts till now..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging 2 list of dicts based on common values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263413/merging-2-list-of-dicts-based-on-common-values)

Comment: @zayora, no.. He used two answers of this question as his new question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use pandas DataFrame : [pandas DataFrame](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.16.2/)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(profile_list)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(marks_list)

>>> result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name'])
>>> print result
   gender  name  chemistry  physics
0  female  suzy         89       95
1    male   jim         69       78

[2 rows x 4 columns]

>>> print result.values.tolist()
[['female', 'suzy', 89L, 95L], ['male', 'jim', 69L, 78L]]

>>> result = result.set_index(['name'])

>>> name = raw_input("Enter student name: ")
Enter student name: suzy

>>> sub = raw_input("Enter subject name: ")
Enter subject name: physics

>>> print result[sub][name]
95
```

Comment: It's probably faster if you have very long dict/list. but is it faster for so few element ?

Comment: This is smart way I guess

Comment: i do have a big dataset ..so this will be helpful..@Aerofol..the resultant value is a Pandas dataframe..how would i convert it back into the format that i need my answer in(list of dicts) ?

Comment: how about this `result.values.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but you have some hint to start.

```
profile_list = [ { 'name':'suzy', 'gender':'female' },
  {'name':'jim', 'gender':'male' }, ]

marks_list = [ {'name':'suzy', 'physics':95, 'chemistry':89 },
{ 'name':'jim', 'physics':78, 'chemistry':69 }, ]

final_list = []

for profile in profile_list:
  for marks in marks_list:
    if profile['name'] == marks['name']:
      a = dict(marks)
      a.pop('name')
      final_list.append(dict(name=profile['name'], **a))
```

Comment: @Lumy..this is very nice and does the job..just to understand..what does the **a do ?

Comment: I'm sorry but fort this question there is only one answer RTFM https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict