# Merging 2 list of dicts based on common values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas

So I have 2 list of dicts which are as follows:

```
list1 = [
{'name':'john',
'gender':'male',
'grade': 'third'
},
{'name':'cathy',
'gender':'female',
'grade':'second'
},
]

list2 = [
{'name':'john',
'physics':95,
'chemistry':89
},
{'name':'cathy',
'physics':78,
'chemistry':69
},
]
```

The output list i need is as follows:

```
final_list = [
{'name':'john',
'gender':'male',
'grade':'third'
'marks': {'physics':95, 'chemistry': 89}
},
{'name':'cathy',
'gender':'female'
'grade':'second'
'marks': {'physics':78, 'chemistry': 69}
},
]
```

First i tried with iteration as follows:

```
final_list = []
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        if item1['name'] == item2['name']:
            temp = dict(item_2)
            temp.pop('name')
            final_result.append(dict(name=item_1['name'], **temp))
```

However,this does not give me the desired result..I also tried pandas..limited experience there..

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)
>>> result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name'])
```

However,i am clueless how to get the data back to the original format i need it in..Any help

Comment: why is cathy with kathy?

Comment: Also, dicts should be `[{'physics':78, 'chemistry': 69}]` with curly brackets.

Comment: fixed that as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first merge both dataframes

```
In [144]: df = pd.DataFrame(list1).merge(pd.DataFrame(list2))
```

Which would look like,

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]:
   gender   grade   name  chemistry  physics
0    male   third   john         89       95
1  female  second  cathy         69       78
```

Then create a marks columns as a dict

```
In [146]: df['marks'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[['chemistry', 'physics']].to_dict()], axis=1)

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
   gender   grade   name  chemistry  physics  \
0    male   third   john         89       95
1  female  second  cathy         69       78

                                  marks
0  [{u'chemistry': 89, u'physics': 95}]
1  [{u'chemistry': 69, u'physics': 78}]
```

And, use `to_dict(orient='records')` method of selected columns of dataframe

```
In [148]: df[['name', 'gender', 'grade', 'marks']].to_dict(orient='records')
Out[148]:
[{'gender': 'male',
  'grade': 'third',
  'marks': [{'chemistry': 89L, 'physics': 95L}],
  'name': 'john'},
 {'gender': 'female',
  'grade': 'second',
  'marks': [{'chemistry': 69L, 'physics': 78L}],
  'name': 'cathy'}]
```

Comment: works like a charm..one final thing..what is the 'L' that is appended to the end of the integer values and how can i avoid them..

Comment: Use `x[['chemistry', 'physics']].astype(int).to_dict()` or `astype(float)`?

Answer (score 1):

Using your pandas approach, you can call

```
result.to_dict(orient='records')
```

to get it back as a list of dictionaries. It won't put `marks` in as a sub-field though, since there's nothing telling it to do that. `physics` and `chemistry` will just be fields on the same level as the rest.

You may also be having problems because your `name` is `'cathy`' in the first list and `'kathy'` in the second, which naturally won't get merged.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want a list of dicts as output, you can easily do what you want without pandas, use a dict to store all the info using the names as the outer keys, doing one pass over each list not like the `O(n^2)` double loops in your own code:

```
out = {d["name"]: d for d in list1}
for d in list2:
    out[d.pop("name")]["marks"] = d


from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(list(out.values()))
```

Output:

```
[{'gender': 'female',
  'grade': 'second',
  'marks': {'chemistry': 69, 'physics': 78},
  'name': 'cathy'},
 {'gender': 'male',
  'grade': 'third',
  'marks': {'chemistry': 89, 'physics': 95},
  'name': 'john'}]
```

That reuses the dicts in your lists, if you wanted to create new dicts:

```
out = {d["name"]: d.copy() for d in list1}

for d in list2:
    k = d.pop("name")
    out[k]["marks"] = d.copy()

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(list(out.values()))
```

The output is the same:

```
[{'gender': 'female',
  'grade': 'second',
  'marks': {'chemistry': 69, 'physics': 78},
  'name': 'cathy'},
 {'gender': 'male',
  'grade': 'third',
  'marks': {'chemistry': 89, 'physics': 95},
  'name': 'john'}]
```

Comment: @Padraic..this is nice..there is something i wanted your opinion on since you have answered quite a few of my queries..when should one use something like pandas or numpy and when should one use the conventional approach..is the former always faster..is there a rule of thumb i can follows..

Comment: @Amistad, there is no one answer, if you really cared about performance you would look to numpy or pandas but that also depends of what you actually want to do with the data, in your case because you want a dict I think the code above would be what I would use and it has the advantage of all being done with the standard lib. I also changed the code to use just regular dicts

Answer (score 1):

create a function that will add a `marks` column , this columns should contain a dictionary of `physics` and `chemistry` marks

```
def create_marks(df):
    df['marks'] = { 'chemistry' : df['chemistry'] , 'physics' : df['physics'] }
    return df

result_with_marks = result.apply( create_marks , axis = 1)

Out[19]:
gender  grade   name    chemistry   physics            marks
male    third   john    89             95   {u'chemistry': 89, u'physics': 95}
female  second  cathy   69             78   {u'chemistry': 69, u'physics': 78}
```

then convert it to your desired result as follows

```
result_with_marks.drop( ['chemistry' , 'physics'], axis = 1).to_dict(orient = 'records')

Out[20]:
[{'gender': 'male',
  'grade': 'third',
  'marks': {'chemistry': 89L, 'physics': 95L},
  'name': 'john'},
 {'gender': 'female',
  'grade': 'second',
  'marks': {'chemistry': 69L, 'physics': 78L},
  'name': 'cathy'}]
```